# Rough book or draft notebook?

Tags: word-request

I've looked up translations for the French word “cahier de brouillon,” and I've gotten two translations: “rough book” and “draft notebook.”

I'm talking about a small (note?)book wherein you write rough notes/make drafts.

How do Americans call it?

Comment: Based on the images I find online for cahier de brouillon, it would seem the closest thing we have is called a *notebook*.  It looks like the paper in a cahier de brouillon is a specific kind of multi-lined paper with large, graph cells on it.  I don't know that I've seen such paper commonly available in the U.S.

Answer (score 1):

If it's a generic book with empty (or lined...) pages, you probably want a *journal*.

If you want to make drawings and prefer thicker or specialized paper, you need a *sketchbook*.

The thin booklets usec by many European students ("Cahier d'exercices" in French)  are rather unusual in the US, most students use *notebooks*, which are bound with a wire spiral and often perforated pages for easier removal.

Answer (score 1):

"Rough book" according to Wordreference Dictionary.
Also, in British English, "jotter" may not be a bad choice.
No idea about the American equivalent though.